# (QGIS) Georeferencer issue - georeference image wrong location

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I try to use the georeferencer to move a raster image just a few meters. The reference layer and the image I want to georeference are both in 4326.

The output layer has an extent:

`Extent -5.6883436311414552,-2030.7353593680741142 : 2127.9033673546623504,1.7335159492328458`

Which is in a completely different order than you would expect based on the projection.

[image: GCP window]

[image: Reference window]

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug that has been fixed, but the binaries are currently unavailable (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/51197

Current workaround is:

1. Delete the image georeference information. **
2. Set the project CRS to WGS 84.
3. Perform image georeferencing.

** As a user of [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com), I recommend converting TIF to PNG and back to TIF.

Comment: What do you mean with 1. Delete the image georeference information

Comment: What Comrade Che is saying is if your file has a tfw (or some other world file like jgw) delete it.  If you have a geoTiff see this post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27947/is-there-a-way-to-erase-geotiff-header.

Comment: @N_LLC See update.