# Deleting GeoTIFF Header/Spatial Reference data using open source software

Tags: coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, editing, metadata, delete

I'm looking for a way to delete only the Header/Spatial Reference information from .tif DEM files, using QGIS or other open source tools.

I need to specifically remove this data from the DEMs while preserving other embedded metadata relating to max & min elevation etc. so they can be used in a 3D modelling program that requires it that way.

This can be achieved in Global Mapper with the *Don't Write GeoTIFF Header* option in the GeoTIFF Export dialog, and in ArcCatalog by right-clicking on a Tiff file and clearing the Spatial Reference information, see images below.

[image: Global Mapper - Don't Write GeoTIFF Header export option]

[image: ArcCatalog - Clear Spatial Reference]

I'm aware of [Is there a way to erase GeoTIFF header?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27947/is-there-a-way-to-erase-geotiff-header) which asks a similar question, but as far as I can tell the answers provided only offer solutions for changing/correcting the spatial data, or removing all metadata and creating a generic .tif file.

Do you have any suggestions for specifically removing the header/spatial reference data?

I'm primarily a 3D visualiser and not an advanced QGIS user.

Comment: Roughly how big are the files in pixels? Some tools might insist on showing them visually and exhaust RAM. Modern GIMP or https://www.photome.de/ might work otherwise

Comment: Please decide whether it is QGIS or another particular open source GIS software that you wish to ask about in this question. I suggest focusing it on GDAL since your broad question already has an answer for that.

Comment: I strongly disagree about the need for user to choose a tool. There might be a free tool that is perfect for the job which they do not know. An arbitrary limitation for a specific tool would lead to a non-optimal answer

Comment: @bugmenot123 the files can range from several hundred to several thousand pixels wide/high, it depends on the size of the site and the resolution of the available elevation data. And you're right, I don't know enough about the available software options to limit my question to a specific program.

Comment: @PolyGeo if QGIS can perform this task it would be great news, as it's the GIS program I'm most familar with. GDAL remains a bit of a mystery to me - for example when a forum post says something like "use gdal_translate", I have no idea if they're referring to an operation performed within QGIS, or within a different program, or if gdal_translate is the name of a piece of software that I need to install. I'm currently trying to read up on it but have yet to gain a clear understanding. You mentioned that my broad question already has an answer - could you please clarify what that answer is?

Comment: @JeremyLondonMDL I was refering to the answer at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/458836/115

Answer (score 1):

I think that gdal_edit  https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html can do what you want with the `-unsetgt` option

> **-unsetgt**
>
> Remove the georeference information.

This tool edits the metadata in-place without a need to make a new copy of the file.

Please tell if you would still need a tfw file because it is too late to create it once the georeferencing information is removed.

Comment: This sounds promising. Is it something that can be done within QGIS, or does it require separate/standalone software? I’ve been reading up about GDAL but am still struggling to understand exactly what it is and how it works. I do require a .tfw, but as a first step I would normally create a copy of my .tif file with an associated world file by adding tfw | yes under Advanced Parameters in the QGIS Translate tool.

Comment: Do you require the answer to be about qgis? Then please tag the question accordingly. Otherwise please mark this answer as solution and appeal the closing of the question.